# Google QUERY function won't pull data despite having uniform data type

Tags: google-sheets

There is definitely going to be a really simple solution for this but I am *so* frustrated with it.

So I have a Google Sheets tool which is used for data collection. The workbook is divided into daily sheets, with which we're tracking attendance of both registered and unregistered members. Both types of members have different types of member numbers (1000 vs. UNREG1001.)

In the data collection tool I used =importRange in this first sheet, and then planned to use =query on each subsequent sheet. I wanted to do this so I could do a batch update of the member/non-member database at the end of each week. But my query formula, despite being the simplest thing in the world, won't pull the UNREG numbers, just the attached names. I reformatted the data to plain text on both the source of the imported range and the data collection tool but that's not fixing the issue. Is there another workaround for this?

My query formula is literally just =query(guests,"select A,B")

Thanks a bunch

Comment: As Erik said in his comment, would be much better if you could post a sample sheet with sample data and a mock up of the result that you are looking for. Its not clear what you are trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QUERY` is designed to pull the most common type from each column, and it will ignore the least common type altogether. Formatting in the source or destination sheet doesn't change the type; it just "disguises it" locally.

But if you aren't actually `QUERY`ing anything other than the two columns of source data, why are you using `QUERY` at all?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason for using `QUERY` is because staff using the tool will frequently add new nonmembers to the bottom of the list. I want these new records to roll over to each new sheet.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. Of course, you haven't shared a link to your sheet, so we can't see your data or layout. But I see no reason for the QUERY here at all, if it is "literally just" =query(guests,"select A,B"). It's clear that "guests" is a named range. But you could just use =ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(guests,ROWS(guests),2) or skip the named range altogether and just use =ArrayFormula(sourcesheetname!A:B).

Comment: This was the most helpful answer; there were a few workarounds that are more efficient than using query, and ARRAY_CONSTRAIN was the most helpful one. Thanks!